# Find sum of all odd number in given range

Tags: javascript, java, loops, for-loop

You are given a number stored in a variable with the name N

You have to print N  lines such that on each line you find the sum of all odd numbers in the range of[1,i], where i represents all the numbers in the range of[1,N]

For example, consider the value stored inN = 3

Then, first we find the sum of all even numbers, in the range of [1,1], which comes out to be 1, as there is one odd number (1) in the range

Then, we find the sum of all even numbers, in the range of [1,2], which comes out to be 1, as there is only 1 odd number (1). Hence, the sum becomes 1

Finally, we find the sum of all even numbers in the range of [1,3], which comes out to be 4, as there are two odd numbers (1,3) in the given range. Hence, the sum becomes 4

Comment: so you used **odd** in title and partially **even** in text... strange since this week we got a lot of questions about summing even numbers in range (trying to avoid it being somehow recognized?)